# Ruby on rails - ActiveModel association with array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, activerecord, activemodel

i'm building a RoR app
this is my original scenario:

2 models, Clienti and Interventi

```
class Clienti < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :interventi, :dependent => :destroy, :foreign_key => "cliente_id"
......
end
```

---

```
class Interventi < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :clienti, :foreign_key => "cliente_id"
.........
end
```

this is a simple one-to-many relation, each "clienti" has many "interventis" (iterventi is a kind of job in my app).

Today i need to convert this relation from one-to-many to many-to-many, each "interventi" need to have more then one "clienti", so i think i have to change the "cliente_id" column in DB from int to text and store an array of "Clienti's ids" (is it the good way? )

My question is: if it's the good way, how can i keep the association in model so i can still use something like "Clienti.Interventi.count" ?

Thanks to all!

Comment: You're gonna have to make a 3rd model to set up a many to many relationship. If you read up on the official Rails guide, you'd have what you need to set this up. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: The Rails way to go about this is to add a new model in between that acts as a join table (and might have additional attributes in the future). If you can come up with a good name, use that. If not, use `ClientiInterventi`. It will belong_to both Clienti and Interventi; C + I will both have_many ClientiInterventi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need a join model to do this kind of many-to-many association. By convention, you could call it `clienti_interventi`

```
class Clienti
  has_many :clienti_interventis
  has_many :interventis, through: :clienti_interventis
end

class Interventi
  has_many :clienti_interventis
  has_many :clientis, through: :clienti_interventis
end

class ClientiInterventi
  belongs_to :clienti
  belongs_to :interventi
end
```

With this setup, you can keep doing whatever you were doing, as well as `Clienti.first.interventis.count` or `Interventi.first.clientis.count`